# How to set RSACryptoServiceProvider Public Key?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, public-key

I have a `RSA` public key stored in a file. The file is plain text and reads as:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
Mdflkjlkf8u8f84rkrjfgk8r7u8t758tkjfedfkjldfjhfjdfdjfkdjfkdfdfdfs
Ddfldkfdjfkjljfldfdlfhkdhfkdhfkdhfkdhfkjdffdnodhmndhiufdofhodhfd
xWCnQ6QOIwKqRY6lklk09erjbds6erottgkjirt895t5tixaevJlMmrZGLaITW66
xVjbPvdpjMniFiemtwIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I want to feed this public key to an object of `RSACryptoServiceProvider` and encrypt an arbitrary message using `Encrypt`. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to set `PK`. Any help is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("pub_key.crt");
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
```

Then use `rsa` object.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have `.crt` file in hand. I just have the plain text file

Comment: @Hans `.crt` file can be binary or text - exactly like your example. Store it in any text file and use it as argument for `X509Certificate2` constructor.

Comment: PS: I tested it and it cannot be imported. Maybe this is only the public key part (big numbers) without any structure. You have to look how to load `cert.PublicKey` object with this data.

Comment: See `rsa.ImportCspBlob` method (rsa is RSACryptoServiceProvider).